# How should I build REST resource paths when there is a many to many relationship

Tags: rest

I have users, and I have groups

```
GET /user/1 -> {id:1,name:"john"}
GET /user/2 -> {id:2,name:"sam"}
GET /group/1 -> {id:100,name:"myGroup"}
```

Obviously, group-to-user is a many-to-many relationship. Ignoring the storage implementation, I am trying to figure out the sanest way to represent it.

```
/user/1/group // lists the groups of which "john" is a member, e.g. [100]
/group/100/user // lists the users who are members of "myGroup", e.g. [1]
```

One? The other? Both of them?

To take it one step further, what if I allow sam to see john (but no one else), because they are both members of group 100? Conceptually, LinkedIn or Facebook similarly allow you to see info about someone once you are connected.

So if john (1) requests info about sam (2), should I do:

```
/user/2 // allows it, with some backend mechanism finding the memberships of sam and john, and then finding that they are in the same group?
```

OR

```
/group/1/member/2 // this is john saying, "I want to access user 2 who is a member of group 1 and so am I"
```

The second option makes the request explain why they should be together, and makes the logic far simpler. On the other hand, user 2 already *is* a resource at `/user/2`, so the alternate route seems strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your collections should use a plural form such as:

```
/users
/groups
```

Representing your users and groups depends on your business, I would say that your "users" are first-class citizens, so it should be:

```
/users/{userId}/groups
```

That would return all groups for user identified by its `userId`. Note that `/users/{userId}` could return user's groups as well, but it is up to you.

The following URI would work as well, but then again, it depends on what you want to do:

```
/groups/{groupId}/users
```

> To take it one step further, what if I allow sam to see john (but no one else), because they are both members of group 100? Conceptually, LinkedIn or Facebook similarly allow you to see info about someone once you are connected.

This could be implemented by some sort of Access Control Lists (ACLs). If user A can't see data of B because they are not friends, then querying `/users/B` will return nothing. However, if C (who is friend with B) performs the same request on `/users/B`, he will be able to see data of B.

So I would go for the first option.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the back and forth on plural vs singular. I like singular. Personal preference.

Comment: So your view is, memberships are not a first-class resource, they are just links between first-class resource `user` and first-class resource `group`. So there are sub-resources beneath `/user/:user` and `/group/:group` to retrieve their memberships.

Comment: And for the second part, you prefer having a single `/user/B`, and have the logic validate cross-memberships? Truth, I like the cleanliness of it, too, but think how much easier the business logic implementation is when it already says as part of the URL, "show me B because we are both part of group 100"

Comment: Thinking in term of resources, does the "group-to-user" relation mean anything? I don't think so. So it should not be a resource. Users have a set of groups. Groups have a set of users. That is it.

Comment: For the second part, yes it is a matter of permissions. It is actually easier, because how can the application ensure you are part of group 100? The application will have to check that internally, and same thing for B.

Then again, you expose resources.

Comment: yes, very good point. And so `GET /user/1` retrieves everything about user 1, but not his memberships; `GET /group/100` retrieves everything about group 100 except members; `GET /user/1/groups` retrieves a list of groups' `GET /group/100/users` retrieves a list of user members.

Comment: I guess you meant `GET /group/100/users in the last sentence, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making a separate resource, maybe groupMemberships, which holds the relationship. You can still have something like GET /users/1/groups to get the groups directly, if it was worth it to you.

```
GET /groupMemberships?user=1
GET /groupMemberships?group=100

{
    "href": ".../groupMemberships/abc123"
    "user": {
        "href": "/users/1"
    }
    "group": {
        "href": "/groups/100"
    }
}
```

Comment: OK... why do you prefer this path?